# Retrieve last logon user and login time of remote computer

Tags: powershell, get-winevent

I have the following code. I don't see any property of Win-Event that holds the name of the user that logged in except for the "Account Name" in the "Message" property. How can I extract only the "Account Name" part of the "Message" property?

```
Get-WinEvent -Computer $computer -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=4672} -MaxEvents 1 | Select-Object -Property Message
```

EDIT: I've also tried the following but got an empty string back

```
Get-WinEvent -Computer $computer -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=4672} -MaxEvents 3 | Select @{Name = "Username";Expression = {$_.ReplacementStrings[1]}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems rather roundabout, but it works. there is a `Data=` option in `FilterHashTable`, but i can't figure out how to use it. [*blush*]

in any case, this searches the `.Message` property for `Account Name` and puts the result in the named match property `.AccountName`.

```
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$GWE_Params = @{
    Computer = $ComputerName
    FilterHashtable = @{
        Logname = 'Security'
        ID = '4672'
        }
    MaxEvents = 3
    }

$EventInfo = @(Get-WinEvent @GWE_Params)

[void]($EventInfo[0].Message -match 'Account Name:\s{1,}(?<AccountName>.+)')

$Matches.AccountName
```

output ...

```
SYSTEM
```

i presume you will want to filter out accounts like `system` - that is easily done. [*grin*]